# Is there a non-video/wifi Canon 70D alternative?

Tags: canon

I've been thinking of getting a Canon 70D but I'm not too sure I want to pay extra for video features or even wifi.

Can you guys recommend a Canon DSLR that offers the same picture, sensor, and picture quality features as a Canon 70D but without the video and wifi?

Comment: How many Canon DSLRs are there?  Could you not look up the specs on each?

Answer (score 6):

You are not paying extra for video. [According to this comparison chart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Canon_EOS_digital_cameras) the 1Ds3 was the last camera that does not have video and got released 2007.

Looking explicitly for something that does not have a certain feature will make you pay more, especially if it's a mainstream feature.

Using video or wifi is optional. If you think the 70D is the right camera for you it would be a mistake not to buy it just because it has some features that you don't need.

There are other features in cameras that are rarely use, yet simply standard and always included like aperture preview buttons, replaceable focusing screens, film plane markings, dozens of automatic modes for certain occasions you will never be in,...

Answer (score 3):

No, not really. All the current Canon dSLRs that are less expensive than a 70D will have video and wifi capability in them.  And if you go back for enough for a camera without those capabilities you're not getting the same sensor/image quality.

The difference in pricing between the tiers comes down to the number of physical UI controls, menu selections, build quality, and the sophistication of the AF system for fast-action shooting.  If you got the 70D to get dual-wheel controls and the AF system, there's no lower-cost alternative.

If, however, you're willing to give up some of those nicer UI features but get a newer sensor/processor combo (24mp Digic 6 vs. 20mp Digic 5), then you could go for the 750D/T6i or 760D/T6s, since these are much newer (but lower-tiered) models than the 70D [see [Wikipedia's Canon EOS digital cameras template]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:Canon_EOS_digital_cameras). The 760D even has dual wheels.

Comment: Build quality is also a big factor in price differences. A 5DS is quite a bit more rugged, inside and out, than one of the Rebel models.

Comment: @Caleb. Good point, I'll add it, although I guess I was thinking more the XXD and XXXD/XXXXD Canon tiers.

Comment: Canon has pretty much labeled the 5DS a "studio" camera and if you read between the lines of their press releases and marketing spin they have pretty much admitted it is not as weather sealed and as rugged as other models such as the 7D Mark II or the 1D X. It may be more durable than some of the Rebel series, but it is far from the top of their line in those terms.